# Why does this function result in ['h', '-', '-', '-', '-']?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The function `hangman_guessed(guessed, secret)` is supposed to take a string of guessed characters and a list of "secret" characters.

The function checks every character in the secret list and compares it with each character in the guessed character string to check if the character is in both. If the characters are not the same then the function places a `-` in a temporary list equal to the secret list (so that we can still compare other characters in the guessed list to the original secret list later).

```
def hangman_guessed(guessed, secret):
    modified = secret
    for i1 in range(len(secret)):
        for i2 in range(len(guessed)):
            if secret[i1] == guessed[i2]:
                modified[i1] = secret[i1]
                break
            else:
                modified[i1] = '-'
    return modified
```

For example, when I run `hangman_guessed('hl', ['h','e','l','l','o'])`, it should return `['h', '-', 'l', 'l', '-']`, but currently it returns `['h', '-', '-', '-', '-']`.

The problem here is that only the first character in the guessed list is considered, but I do not know why. It this case, it is expected that the program checks over the `'l'` characters in `['h','e','l','l','o'])` and sets the corresponding characters in the temporary list `modified` to `-`, but to my understanding after the for loop runs again and checks the original `secret` list for `l` characters it should overwrite the `-` in the `modified` list and the result should have the `'l'` characters rather than the `-` characters.

Comment: `modified` and `secret` are references to the *same* list

Comment: you'll need to copy secret: `modified=secret[:]`, now they are point to same list

Comment: Why do you need `break`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Really? Didn't know Python worked like that? Just to make sure, you meant by modifying `modified` I was actually changing the original list `secret` as well?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yep you got it!

Comment: @rnso I put break there because otherwise it would keep checking if the next guessed characters matched the secret list even though it already found a match, then it would overwrite these characters with a `-` even though they were in the guessed list.

Comment: BTW, You need not use `len()` when looping. `for` is capable of iterating through strings as well.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks, if someone writes an answer with this information (and how I point to a modified list instead of the original) I'll accept it when I get time.

Comment: "by modifying `modified` I was actually changing the original list `secret` as well?" - if you are used to Java it would be the same there.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski You're right. I created a similar function in Java and it did modify the original. I guess I just haven't run into this issue yet (or gave up without knowing why something just didn't work lol). Anyways, for anyone confused as myself (at least for Java), [this](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) helped clear up the whole thing a bit for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`list-comprehension`](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) is *perfectly* suited to what you want to do. We want to create a list of each character (let this be `i`) in `secret` *if* `i` is `in` `guessed` *else* we want to have a hyphen (`"-"`).

```
def hangman_guessed(guessed, secret):
    return [i if i in guessed else "-" for i in secret]
```

and a test to show it works:

```
>>> hangman_guessed('hl', ['h','e','l','l','o'])
['h', '-', 'l', 'l', '-']
```

*As you get more used to the flow of Python, you will find that comprehensions in general are extremely useful as well as being very readable for a whole variety of things.*

---

If for some reason however, you had to use nested `for-loops` and weren't allowed to use the really simple `in` operator, then you need to / can make a couple of corrections to your current code:

- make a copy of the `secret` list first
- iterate through the characters in `guessed`, rather than the indexes

After making these two corrections, the function will look something like:

```
def hangman_guessed(guessed, secret):
    modified = secret[:]
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        for g in guessed:
            if secret[i] == g:
                modified[i] = secret[i]
                break
            else:
                modified[i] = '-'
    return modified
```

which now works:

```
>>> hangman_guessed('hl', ['h','e','l','l','o'])
['h', '-', 'l', 'l', '-']
```

Comment: This is great information, thank you. I am new to Python and used to Java (and I'm starting to recognize the differences). This doesn't necessarily answer my question but is much nicer than the solution I tried to create.

Comment: @JohnDoe I have updated the answer with a working `for-loop` solution **:)**